# Redirect To Login Page When Modal Popup is Clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I know this question has been asked a lot, but I didn't find quite what I was looking for. My parent view of ProcedureEdit has a lot of modals that when a user is timed out, would load my login page. I was able to get my page to redirect instead of loading the login inside the modal, but the ReturnUrl is that of my modal I click. Is there a way to get like the parent action as my ReturnUrl? I will post the code i am currently using, maybe there is a better way to redirect.

Controller

```
    public ActionResult RedirectToLogin(string ReturnURL)
    {
        ReturnUrlModel rum = new ReturnUrlModel();
        rum.returnUrl = ReturnURL;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = ReturnURL;
        return PartialView("RedirectToLogin", rum);
    }
```

View

```
  @model Hospital_Web_Portal.Models.ReturnUrlModel
    <script>
    window.location = '@Url.Action("Login", "Account")' + '?ReturnURL=' + 
    '@Model.returnUrl';
    </script>
```

WebConfig

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/RedirectToLogin" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="false" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: you could do the redirect manually using js and set the returnUrl yourself

Comment: I have like tons and tons of these popups all over, it would be impractical to do.

Comment: you open a popup that makes an ajax request to get the content; and if the auth expired you return from the server html containing a script that will redirect to the login page with the desired returnUrl (which you can also set at the server)

Comment: I mean that is basically what i already posted I am doing. Setting the ReturnURL every time manually just wont work for me.

Comment: what do you mean by "Parent Action" ?

Comment: I dunno if that is the right term, but what i mean by that is if the main View is ProcedureEdit and the modal is lets say AddPrice, when i click on AddPrice instead of the return URL being AddPrice, i need it to be ProcedureEdit. Hope that makes sense

Comment: `'?ReturnURL='  + location.href`; or a hidden input in `_Layout.cshtml` `$('#parenUrl').val()`

Comment: I see what your getting at. I just left work, so I'll work on it later and see if I can't get it to work. Thanks